# Fetch correct value when having identical column-names in two tables - based on max in select

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables, `products` and `image`:

```
SELECT
products.id,
products.name,
MAX(image.angle) AS image_angle,
image.url as image_url,
image.width as image_width,
image.height as image_height
FROM products
JOIN `image` ON (`products`.`id` = `image`.`product_id`)    
WHERE image.width = 100
aND image.height = 200
```

In the image there are different dimensions of the image stored

In the `product` table there is a column called `image_url` and in the `image` table there is an `url` column. T**he above query gives me the correct max value of angle** (from the `image` table), but an incorrect value for `image.url`.

The result could be something like:

```
    (
        [id] => 308
        [name] => Volvo240
        [image__angle] => 4
        [url] => /image/308/1_100_200.png
        [image__width] => 100
        [image__height] => 200
    )
```

The `url` is fetching value from the `product` table, but I want the `url` to fetch value from the `image` table and be (in this case): `/image/308/**4**_100_200.png`

I don't know if it matters, but I'm using CodeIgniter and ActiveRecord to create my query.

Comment: How are you joining the tables? How does the info in `image` relate to that in `products`?

Comment: Sorry.. I've added the join (I have simplified the query a lot to make it easy to udnerstand the issue) Hope it makes the issue more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the product table does not have many rows(10K below), you could use this code:

```
SELECT
    products.id,
    products.name,
    (SELECT image.angle
       FROM image
      WHERE `image`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
        AND `image`.`width` = 100
        AND `image`.`height` = 200
      ORDER BY image.angle DESC
      LIMIT 0, 1) AS image_angle,
    (SELECT image.url
       FROM image
      WHERE `image`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
        AND `image`.`width` = 100
        AND `image`.`height` = 200
      ORDER BY image.angle DESC
      LIMIT 0, 1) AS image_url,
    100 AS image_width,
    200 AS image_height
FROM 
    products
```

If the product table has huge amount of rows, use this code for better performance:

```
    SELECT
        products.id,
        products.name,
        image.angle AS image_angle,
        image.url AS image_url,
        image.width AS image_width,
        iamge.height AS image_height
    FROM 
        products
    JOIN 
        (SELECT product_id, max(angle) AS max_angle
           FROM image
          WHERE width = 100 AND height = 200
          GROUP BY product_id) AS t1 ON (t1.product_id = product.id)
    JOIN 
        image ON (image.product_id = t1.product_id AND image.angle = t1.max_angle)
   WHERE 
        image.width = 100 AND 
        image.height = 200
```

But the code above required your image table's record are unique on (product_id, angle, width, height), otherwise you may get multiple rows for one product.

Comment: Worked like a charm after som minor modifications :-) Now it's up to me to get it to work with ActiveRecord/CodeIgniter also, but that's another story :-) Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

use sub query like following:

```
SELECT 
    products.id,
    products.name,
    (select 
            MAX(image.angle)
        from
            products
        WHERE
            image.width = 100 aND image.height = 200) AS image_angle,
    image.url as image_url,
    image.width as image_width,
    image.height as image_height
FROM
    products
     JOIN `image` ON (`products`.`id` = `image`.`product_id`) 
WHERE
    image.width = 100 aND image.height = 200
```

you can remove where condition from sub query (according to your need).

Comment: Fair enough. It still didn't work though as expected. I got only one row, but I've got my answer now! Thanks for helping! The +1 was from me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need add GROUP BY  to the product.id or image.id 
Also Add ORDER BY on angle.

```
SELECT
products.id,
products.name,
products.category_id,
image.angle AS image_angle,
image.url as image_url,
image.width as image_width,
image.height as image_height
FROM products

WHERE image.width = 100
aND image.height = 200
GROUP BY `products.id`
ORDER BY `image.angle` DESC
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. The ordering itself is not the issue. The issue that I get incorrect image_url.